# Voicing of sibilants before liquids, after voiced vowels?

Tags: phonetics, vowels, phonemes, phonotactics, sibilants

I just ran across an in­ter­est­ing ques­tion from a friend about
the voic­ing of sibi­lants in English. She was ask­ing why English
speak­ers pro­nounce the word *mus­lim* as *muZlim* (with a voiced
sibi­lant) whereas those from the Mid­dle East pro­nounce the word
with a true /s/ (un­voiced).

As a stu­dent of the Semitic lan­guages, this was quite in­ter­est­ing
to me be­cause I could ex­plain the un­voiced sibi­lant as the
orig­i­nal phoneme in the Semitic form of the word. I could not,
how­ever, com­pellingly ex­plain the voic­ing in English.

So here is my ques­tion: Is the voic­ing of the /s/ in *mus­lim*
caused by the fol­low­ing /l/? Com­pa­ra­ble words in­clude *muslin*,
*gosling*, *As­lan* (not ex­actly and English word, but a fic­tional
char­ac­ter in English lit­er­a­ture).  In ev­ery case, we voice
the sibi­lant as a /z/. (In­ci­den­tally, is this a fea­ture unique
to Amer­i­can English? Do Bri­tish English speak­ers keep these
sibi­lants un­voiced?)

As I got think­ing about this, I then started to won­der if the /l/
wasn’t the fac­tor caus­ing voic­ing in the sibi­lant. It oc­curred
to me that ev­ery case has a voiced vowel pre­ced­ing the /s/. Could
it be this voiced vowel caus­ing the voic­ing of the sibi­lant? I’m
very cu­ri­ous about this and would ap­pre­ci­ate any in­formed
re­sponses you might have!

Comment: "Could it be this voiced vowel causing the voicing of the sibilant?" **/////** Aren't vowels always voiced? +++++++ "Is the voicing of the /s/ in "muslim" caused by the following /l/?" ///// What about 'whistling'?

Comment: Well, the Chronicles of Narnia were written by a devout Christian, and I don't think he would want the character that symbolizes Jesus himself to have such an unfortunate name as *Ass-lan*. (Seriously though, it probably has to do with the single 's' before the 'l' as opposed to a double 's', as in *hassling*).

Comment: Sometimes — consider *paisley*, but not always — consider *Chrysler*

Comment: Also *translate* and *brisling*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul *Brisling* can be pronounced either way.

Comment: @MicahWindsor, Yes, I didn't clarify my comment ... I meant *translate* and *brisling* can have both /s/ and /z/. :)

Comment: For me, ***bristling*** (seething, angry) and ***brisling*** (sardine-like small fish) are a "minimal pair". You don't get to *choose* whether to enunciate the /t/ - it depends entirely on the intended meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You do get to choose whether to syllabicize the /l/ though; for me, _bristling_ can have 3 syllables, but never _brisling_ (though I agree with you about the voicing).

Comment: It seems to me (and I'm no phonologist) that the voicing is least common before stressed syllables. One would never voice the /s/ in _asleep_, but _translate_ can swing either way. In English, the tendency (and that's all that this is -- a tendency) is for progressive assimilation in clusters, at least across morpheme boundaries, but this is regressive (the voicing of the liquid is copied by the preceding sibilant).

Comment: No, there is no phonological rule requiring or permitting a voiceless alveolar fricative (i.e. /s/) to become voiced before a voiced phoneme. If anything the reverse is true: a voiceless fricative may cause the full or partial devoicing of a following voiced consonant (in particular voiced plosives). There are many words and prefixes where we see free variation between /s/ and /z/, but this is lexical and not, synchronically, the resut of any phonological or phonetic process.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's odd. I've always thought of myself as just about the "laziest" speaker I know (don't bother with any words / syllables that aren't *essential* to express the intended meaning). But now you've flagged it up I realise I very often end up enunciating an extra syllable in words like that. So ***traveling*** is always 3 syllables to me (regardless of whether I go all American with the single /l/ spelling). It seems somehow *harder* for me to make that transition switch from /v/ to /l/ without "syllabicizing" the latter.

Comment: It is amazing the amount of unexamined individual variation one indulges in, every minute of one's speaking life. The stream of speech is like Heraclitus's river -- one can never step in the same stream twice, because it's always different; not just in the atoms, like the river, but in the actual muscle gestures, and their resultant sounds. This is what digs new river channels and changes pronunciation over generations.

Comment: I don't buy this Middle East thing. There are two English pronunciations. Nevertheess, I say Muslim with an /z/ and Islam with an /z/. The pronunciation serves as a left/right code for some in the US.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the common pronunciation of *muslim* with /z/ does indicate that there is likely some analogy going on with words like *muslin* or *gosling*. The l doesn't "cause" /z/ in the sense of a requirement or sound rule, as the pronunciations of *Muslim* with /sl/ and /zl/ both exist and contrast with each other.

The pronunciation of the letter S as /s/ or /z/ doesn't follow very predictable rules.

#### /zl/ only occurs between syllables (as /z.l/), never at the start of a syllable

The sound preceding the S is definitely relevant. When "sl" occurs at the start of a word in English, the "s" is always pronounced as a voiceless fricative. The same applies to "sl" in the middle of a word when it is interpreted as the start of a syllable (or where it is originally word-initial), as in *bob**sl**ed, mud**sl**ide, pay**sl**ip, a**sl**eep.*

The pronunciation of "sl" as /zl/ only occurs as far as I know in contexts where the consonants can be interpreted as belonging to separate syllables, as in/ˈgɑz.lɪŋ/. So it has to be preceded by a sound that can come before syllable-final /z/—which means a voiced sound (either a vowel sound or a voiced consonant sound).

To be clear, there are (non-native) words spelled with "zl" that you can hear pronounced with syllable-initial /zl/, such as *zloty.* So syllable-initial /zl/ isn't absolutely impossible for English speakers to pronounce; it just isn't a possible pronunciation at the start of a syllable spelled with "sl".

#### But /s.l/ is also possible between syllables

We can see that "s" doesn't always represent /z/ when followed by /l/ in a separate syllable. Compound words are a clear counterexample: *gaslamp* and *gaslight* have /s.l/ rather than /z.l/.

Additionally, words with the suffixes *-less* or *-ly* don't show voicing. With *-ly,* the many words ending in *-ously* show this. Most *-less* examples are spelled with "ssl", but there are also rare examples like *gasless* or *focusless* that show that this applies regardless of the spelling with one or two Ss.

#### some words currently or historically show variation between /z.l/ and /s.l/

Variation between /z.l/ and /s.l/ seems to be particularly common with prefixed words. The commenters have mentioned the *trans*-prefixed word *translate.*

Some words starting with *dis-* are pronounced with /dɪs/ and some with /dɪz/ (e.g. *disease, disaster*). Words where *dis-* is followed by a consonant are typically pronounced with /dɪs/ in contemporary English. However, there is evidence that some speakers have used voiced /dɪz/ before l in words like *dislike, dislodge.* That pronunciation is given in John Walker's *[Critical Pronouncing Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=9OsIAAAAQAAJ&q=dis#v=onepage&q=dislike&f=false)* of 1823 (§435); the fact that Walker feels the need to say that these words "ought" to be pronounced with a /z/ sound suggests that he also was familiar with pronunciations of these words starting with /dɪsl/.

#### Comparison: voiced S before other consonants

Other spelling patterns that you might compare this to are *sn* (as in *Disney*) *sm* (as in *cosmic*), and more rarely, *sr* (*Israel*) or *sb* (*husband*). As with *sl,* word-initial or syllable-initial *sn* or *sm* always have a voiceless fricative; /zn/ and /zm/ are only possible across syllables. The productive suffix *-ness* does not trigger voicing of preceding /s/, so we have /sn/ in *consciousness, righteousness,* etc.

Syllable-initial *sr* and *sb* do not exist within the basic English sound system, although they can be found in recently loaned words or proper nouns like *Sri Lanka* or *Sbarro* that are pronounced in various ways.

Comment: The pronunciation of the letter S doesn't follow any rules, it's weird. See *resource* and *resound* - I guess the voicing is because of the prefix *re-*... who knows.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: I've written a more general post about the pronunciation of S as /s/ vs. /z/: [When to pronounce ‹s› as /z/ in the middle of words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/82435/18197) but there definitely aren't simple rules to it. Many of the patterns that can be identified have exceptions.

Comment: I words like *muzzle* the /z/ would be deemed the onset of the syllable /zl/ under a maximal onset principle analysis.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: My phrasing "the start of a syllable" in this answer should be interpreted as "in the onset of a syllable". If [l̩] is treated as the consonant /l/ occupying a syllable nucleus, then [zl̩] is a third case that I don't cover. But I would phonemicize [zl̩] as /zəl/ with a schwa phoneme as the nucleus and /l/ as the coda.